# Random number generator gives consistent results

Tags: c++, random, coin-flipping

So the goal of my program is to simulate flipping a coin. I'm trying to use a random number generator to generate the number 1 or 2, 1 for heads, 2 for tails.

However I keep getting Tails as the result, where am I going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // Require for rand()
#include <ctime>   // For time function to produce the random number
using namespace std;

// This program has three functions: main and first.

// Function Prototypes
void coinToss();

int main()
{
  int flips;

   cout << "How many times would you like to flip the coin?\n";
   cin >> flips;    // user input
  if (flips > 0)
  {
     for (int count = 1; count <= flips; count++) // for loop to do action based on user input
    { 
     coinToss();    // Call function coinToss
    }
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Please re run and enter a number greater than 0\n";
  }
  cout << "\nDone!\n";
  return 0;
}

void coinToss() //retrieve data for function main
{
  unsigned seed = time(0);  // Get the system time.
  srand(seed); // Seed the random number generator
  int RandNum = 0;

    RandNum = 2 + (rand() % 2); // generate random number between 1 and 2

    if (RandNum == 1) 
    {
      cout << "\nHeads"; 
    }
    else if (RandNum == 2)
    {
      cout << "\nTails";
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you asking here?

Comment: You should move the   srand(time(0)); to the beginning of your program such that it is executed only once.

Comment: BTW, C++11 introduces the header [<random>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/)

Comment: The "goal of your program" reads much like a homework assignment. That is not the purpose of this site. If you have a specific problem, feel free to ask a *specific* question, but don't toss your homework questions in here waiting for someone to figure out what is asked and do the coding for you.

Comment: @ArneMertz, sorry about that, seemed pretty stupid after you mentioned it (and frankly quite lazy). Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should move the srand function to the begin of main.
if you call this function twice in the same second you will get the same numbers from random()

also you should change

```
RandNum = 2 + (rand() % 2);
```

to

```
RandNum = 1 + (rand() % 2);
```

rand() % 2 will result in 0 or 1, so adding 1 will result in 1 or 2

Comment: Thank, that worked! It also makes a lot of sense! Was I receiving the same value because srand was giving the same value since it was continuously being called over the same time interval?

(not sure if I used the correct jargon, please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @user3714056 `rand()` is only a *pseudo random* generator. It takes a value called "seed", and performs some calculation on it to generate a return value (the "random" value) and a new seed. `srand()` is used to initialize the seed, by performing some calculations on its argument. If you call `srand` with a given time `t`, it will generate a seed `s`, and the first call of `rand()` gives you some random number `r` and set the seed to another value `s2`. If you call `srand` again immediately, it will generate the same seed `s` again, and the next call to `rand` will give you the same `r` again.